# PROBLEMA AL SUBIR UN PROYECTO A MI SERVIDO VPS

Tags: laravel, host

Cuando realice el deploy de mi aplicación laravel a mi servidor VPS, el metodo Storage::url me sigue tomando la URL de mi proyecto como si siguiera en local, y por lo tanto no me muestra las imagenes y archivos guardados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe aclarar que aun no le tengo un dominio al proyecto, si no que entro con ip suministrada por el VPS y quisiera saber como cambiar la ruta del Storage::url a la del VPS en producción. Agradecería mucho sus ayudas.

**Nota**: Ya cambie la va variable de entorno `APP_URL` a la ip de mi host VPS pero sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder al storage no es posible desde la carpeta public, puedes cambiar el driver del disco a public pero te tomaría mas trabajo, creo que es mejor que crees en enlace simbólico con el comando

```
php artisan storage:link
```

este debes ejecutarlo desde la terminal